# Python webservice client

Tags: python, web-services

Can anyone make a webservice client in python from the following JAX-WS API?

https://109.231.73.12:8090/API?wsdl

As I'm running this of a virtual server it's self signed. Both the username and password are 'querty123'

We can get it to work in php just fine not python.

So a working example explaining how you managed to do it would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`suds`](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) library makes this a snap in Python:

```
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> url = 'https://109.231.73.12:8090/API?wsdl'
>>> client = Client(url, username='qwerty123', password='qwerty123')
>>> client.service.addition(1, 2)
3
>>> client.service.hello('John')
HelloJohn
>>> client.service.xToThePowerOfy(2, 16)
18
>>> print client # automagic documentation

Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.4 (beta)  build: R685-20100513

Service ( BasicService ) tns="http://service.basic.com/"
   Prefixes (1)
      ns0 = "http://service.basic.com/"
   Ports (1):
      (BasicPort)
         Methods (3):
            addition(xs:int x, xs:int y, )
            hello(xs:string name, )
            xToThePowerOfy(xs:int x, xs:int y, )
         Types (6):
            addition
            additionResponse
            hello
            helloResponse
            xToThePowerOfy
            xToThePowerOfyResponse
```